# How to change four bytes into float32 in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I use `tf.FixedLengthRecordReader` to read file and get a list of uint8 tensors. And I want to transform the first four bytes into one `float32`.

For example, the first four bytes are 0xAA,0xBB,0xCC,0xDD, I want to get 0xAABBCCDD and change it into `float32`. We known if we use C++, it is easy that we just use (double*)address(0xAA). But how can I do in tensorflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`tf.decode_raw`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/decode_raw), which has an `out_type` argument that specifies the cast to be done, e.g.

```
record_bytes = tf.decode_raw(value, tf.float32)
```

Comment: But after the first four bytes, I also have uint8 data, if I use `record_bytes = tf.decode_raw(value, tf.float32)`, the all bytes will be transformed to float32

Comment: You could split your input accordingly and call `tf.decode_raw` on the different parts with the appropriate `out_type`.